# in Q, how to speed up unicoin mining?

Tags: r, unicoins, q-lang

There's a new language `Q`, based on `R`, which was based on `S` ... you get the idea.

Sadly, `Q` appears to be very slow in automining unicoins.  Plus, `Q` : we don't have TIME for your little games!

Comment: that's the weirdest question I ever read by somebody with a considerable reputation

Comment: @Яaffael  I do my best to be weird :-).  I apologize- I actually had no idea there was an actual "q" in software at all!

Comment: I voted this down purely to see the unicorn animation zap your score.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unicoins

Comment: I just used C# because it's easy, the performance is important, sure but another point is to start early!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Next to the well-known `Q` JavaScript library, you might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages#Q :-)

Comment: @Яaffael, according to my screen, Carl only has 831 reputation. Sorry Carl.

Comment: @Bergi I think we need to create a new tag

Comment: @Bergi hmmm your link says `Q` is im-`Pure`   :-)

Answer (score 4):

Clearly Q is backwards compatible to R so it inherits its speed. This is by design. Happy mining!